# "Vector Iterators Incompatible" when calculating distance between two iterators

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, stl

I'm having an issue which I cannot quite find the cause of.

At a certain point in my code I'm returning the distance between two std::vector iterators, one being the result of an insert operation on a vector and the other pointing to the beginning of the vector. The idea is to return the index of the newly inserted object.

Everything works perfectly when I phrase the code like this

```
const_iterator (or auto) it = insert(object);
return it - begin();
```

However, if I try to make a one liner out of it

```
return insert(object) - begin();
```

I get the aforementioned "Vector Iterators Incompatible" assertion.

begin() is implemented as:

```
MyClass::iterator MyClass::begin()
{
  return m_container.begin();
}
```

and insert() is implemented as:

```
MyClass::iterator MyClass::insert(MyObject *object)
{
  if (object)
  {
    const_iterator it = std::lower_bound(begin(), end(), object, DereferencedLess<MyObject >());

    if (it == end() || *(*it) != *object)
      return m_container.insert(it, object);
  }

  return end();
}
```

Brief outline of the class:

```
MyClass {
  ...
  iterator  begin();
  const_iterator begin() const;
  iterator  insert(MyObject*);

  ...
  protected:
  std::vector<MyObject*> m_container;
}
```

and for completeness' sake

```
template<typename T>
struct DereferencedLess
{ inline bool operator()(const T *p1, const T *p2) const { return *p1 < *p2; } };
```

I would very much like to understand why the assertion happens. From what I can see the iterators are of the same type and both insert() and begin() are working on the same vector. All the necessary typedefs are in place as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector::insert` invalidates the iterators. In expression `insert(object) - begin()` `begin()` can be called before or after `insert`. If it is called before than it is invalidated by `insert()`. [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.

Whereas when you do:

```
const_iterator (or auto) it = insert(object);
return it - begin();
```

`begin()` is called after `insert()` and hence returns a valid iterator.

Comment: Yes, I understand that insert() invalidates the iterators (well, the ones following the inserted object anyway), but how/why can begin() be called before insert()?

Comment: @azrael Updated the answer for you.

Comment: "@Maxim Egorushkin" Thanks for that. Will have to properly check out that link you've provided.